# How to allow each article to be on its own page

Tags: php

I want to create a news website using html and php. All the content is stored in a mysql database.
I need each news story to be on its own page without me having to manually create all pages in the development folder.

I have not yet started working on the project. I am still conceptualising how I'm going to create the website.
Here is the code on the method I plan on using to retrieve articles. As far as I know, this will simply throw all articles on one page.

```
//get content from db
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//display content
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object ($result)) {
print "<h1>" . $obj->title . "</h1>";
print "by:" . $obj->journalist . "<br>";
print "<blockquote>" . $obj->lede . "</blockquote> writes" . $obj->journalist . "<br>";
print "published on:" . $obj->date . "<hr>";
print "<p>" . $obj->story . "</p>";
$id = $obj->newsid;
if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
echo "<form action = './includes/delete.php' method = post>
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'id' value ='$id'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Delete'>
</form>";
}
if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
echo "<form action = './includes/update.php' method = post>
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'id' value ='$id'>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Update'>
</form>";
}
}
mysqli_free_result ($result);
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It is iterating through all the records and printing out the results. As you dig into learning the language and using sql, just remember this bit of advice: tackle one thing at a time and make sure you understand exactly how and why it works. I would suggest you look at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo for good solid advice about working with a database.

Comment: 1 news content needed and the content is dynamically replaced by your news ID which is, you need to get all the data related to that news ID to use for displaying on your content.

Answer (score 0):

each article should have an ID or primary key in the database.
next, you can make a page that retrieves ID parameter like :

```
/news.php?id=x
```

and inside the php, you can get the parameter

```
$param = $_GET['id']
```

and the query would be

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=?");    
$stmt->mysqli_bind_param("s",$param);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: No, that is definitely ***not*** how the query ***should*** be written. It is wide open to sql injection. You should never ever trust user input in a query. At the very least you should type cast it as an integer; but even at that, anything short of using prepared statements is considered bad practice.

Comment: Good edit.  That makes your answer a good one, and keeps you from getting down-voted :)